# PHP mixed with html no output

Tags: php, html, linux, apache, loops

It's been over a decade since I've touched anything web related code-wise, so excuse my ignorance. I've mixed some php code with html for a faculty/post-doc reunion page, and surprisingly there are no errors present on the surface. When the php is executed from my linux console it outputs as I would expect, echoing strings back. Once the php is executed from the apache web server it's world of output becomes void (either completely blank or a server 500 code).

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$str = file_get_contents('str.txt');

echo '<html>
<head>
<style>body { background: #130; }</style>
</head>
<body>
<code><span style="display:block;line-height:8px; font-size: 8px; font-weight:bold;white-space:pre;font-family: monospace;color: #0F0; background: #130;">';

$r = preg_match_all("/.?/uim", $str, $m);

for($i=0; $i < sizeof($m[0]); $i++) {
    echo $m[0][$i]; 
    time_nanosleep(0, 50000000);
}

echo '</span></code>
</body>
</html>';

?>
```

edit: mildred uploaded the wrong file, updated -> str.txt can be found here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dbb8ae305d83078d7ae7

Comment: what are you trying to match in that string

Comment: it matches each character from the string so i can output them individually (one at a time).

Comment: its weird, looks like a face or something inside of somewhat like a terminal

Comment: What happens if you comment out the `time_nanosleep`? (Why would you sleep anyway?)

Comment: The sleep is needed to resemble the stdout of tty.

Comment: JavaScript is a way better solution for that purpose

Comment: Would you kindly explain the reasoning behind that?

Comment: Most servers are setup to handle a maximum of X (for exameple 50) simultaneous connections. If a single page takes 6 minutes, thats a waste of resources. That animation could (and should) be done client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to be an issue with your php code, executes fine for me on apache on a test run.  It may be your timeouts for execution on either php or apache->php-fpm or the amount of memory that is assigned for the php process to run in.  What does your apache error log give you when you check the output.  Then we can give you a better answer.

Based on the comments below you will need to use ob_flush() to clear the output buffer so that content is displayed as it becomes available in stead of it displaying at the end of the output.  For what you're trying to do an ajax application may make a bit more sense unless you really want to rely on flushing output.

Also keep in mind with ob_flush even you'll have to update your apache / php settings to actually send data immediately instead of buffering it.  Your html closing statements are also all the way at the bottom.  A better solution as I mentioned before would be to use javascript for the front end with a basic template that calls a seperate php for processing.  On response js will update the page with the additional information.

Comment: There are no errors. Are you getting output in proper html format?

Comment: Yep I get a green page with some text on it.  No errors.  My PHP execution timeout is 399 secs and my apache php-fpm timeout is 400secs.  It did take a really long time to output though which is why I'm pretty sure it's your timeouts.

Comment: I see. It's supposed to output each character one at a time, so I presume this method I've chosen is not adequate.

Comment: Updated my post with additional details provided in your comments.

Answer (score 0):

to match each single character you can use `/(.)/`

like this

```
preg_match_all("/(.)/", $str, $m);
```

or you can ue `str_split` [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

```
str_split($str);
```